# Chutes & Ladders Board Generator (June 2016 Community Challenge)

Tags: c#, game, community-challenge, mvp

This is an "entry" I made for the June 2016 Community Challenge to make a Chutes and Ladders generator. It generates a random number of chutes and ladders with a total delta of -50 and displays their start points, endpoints, and deltas.

Some notes:

- The number of chutes must be at least 2, and the number of ladders at least 1.
- The total delta from chutes must be (-)100 and the total delta from ladders must be 50. This is how I balanced the board to a total delta of -50 while ensuring that there were a decent amount of chutes and ladders.
- I have attempted to use the MVP pattern.

#### ChutesAndLaddersBoardGenerator

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ChutesAndLaddersBoardGenerator
{
    internal static class ChutesAndLaddersBoardGenerator
    {
        private const int BoardSize = 10;

        [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var model = new Generator(BoardSize);
            var view = new ChutesAndLaddersBoardGeneratorView();
            new ChutesAndLaddersBoardGeneratorPresenter(view, model);
            Application.Run(view);
        }
    }
}
```

#### ChutesAndLaddersBoardGeneratorView

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ChutesAndLaddersBoardGenerator
{
    internal partial class ChutesAndLaddersBoardGeneratorView : Form,
        IChutesAndLaddersBoardGeneratorView
    {
        public ChutesAndLaddersBoardGeneratorView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindComponent();
        }

        private void BindComponent()
        {
            generateBoardButton.Click += OnGenerateBoardButtonClick;
        }

        public event Action GenerateBoard;

        private void OnGenerateBoardButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GenerateBoard?.Invoke();
        }

        public void LoadChutesAndLadders(
            List<ChuteOrLadder> chutesAndLadders)
        {
            chutesAndLaddersDisplay.DataSource = chutesAndLadders;
            int totalDelta = 0;
            foreach (var chuteOrLadder in chutesAndLadders)
            {
                totalDelta += chuteOrLadder.Delta;
            }
            totalDeltaLabel.Text = "Total Delta: " + totalDelta;
        }
    }
}
```

#### IChutesAndLaddersBoardGeneratorView

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ChutesAndLaddersBoardGenerator
{
    internal interface IChutesAndLaddersBoardGeneratorView
    {
        event Action GenerateBoard;

        void LoadChutesAndLadders(List<ChuteOrLadder> chutesAndLadders);
    }
}
```

#### ChutesAndLaddersBoardGeneratorPresenter

```
namespace ChutesAndLaddersBoardGenerator
{
    internal class ChutesAndLaddersBoardGeneratorPresenter
    {
        private readonly IChutesAndLaddersBoardGeneratorView view;
        private readonly Generator generator;

        internal ChutesAndLaddersBoardGeneratorPresenter(
            IChutesAndLaddersBoardGeneratorView view,
            Generator generator)
        {
            this.view = view;
            this.generator = generator;
            this.view.GenerateBoard += OnGenerateBoard;
        }

        internal void OnGenerateBoard()
        {
            view.LoadChutesAndLadders(generator.GenerateChutesAndLadders());
        }
    }
}
```

#### Generator

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace ChutesAndLaddersBoardGenerator
{
    internal class BoardSquare
    {
        internal Tuple<int, int> Coordinates { get; set; }
        internal bool HasChuteOrLadder { get; set; }
        internal int SquareNumber { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Coordinates.ToString() + " " + SquareNumber;
        }
    }

    internal class Generator
    {
        private const int TotalChutesDelta = -100;
        private const int TotalDelta = -50;
        private const int TotalLaddersDelta = 50;
        private static Random random;
        private int size;

        internal Generator(int size)
        {
            if (size % 2 != 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Board size must be even!");
            }
            else if (size < 2)
            {
                throw new Exception("Board size must be positive!");
            }
            this.size = size;
            random = new Random();
        }

        internal List<ChuteOrLadder> GenerateChutesAndLadders()
        {
            var board = GenerateBoard();
            var chutesAndLadders = new List<ChuteOrLadder>();
            chutesAndLadders.AddRange(GenerateChutes(board));
            chutesAndLadders.AddRange(GenerateLadders(board));
            return chutesAndLadders;
        }

        private BoardSquare[,] GenerateBoard()
        {
            BoardSquare[,] board = new BoardSquare[size, size];
            int squareNumber = size * size;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                    board[i, j] = new BoardSquare
                    {
                        Coordinates = new Tuple<int, int>(i, j),
                        SquareNumber = squareNumber--,
                        HasChuteOrLadder = false
                    };
                }
                for (int j = size - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    board[i + 1, j] = new BoardSquare
                    {
                        Coordinates = new Tuple<int, int>(i, j),
                        SquareNumber = squareNumber--,
                        HasChuteOrLadder = false
                    };
                }
            }
            return board;
        }

        private List<ChuteOrLadder> GenerateChutes(BoardSquare[,] board)
        {
            var chutes = new List<ChuteOrLadder>();
            var numberOfChutes = random.Next(2, board.GetLength(0));
            int[] deltas = new int[numberOfChutes + 1];
            deltas[0] = 0;
            deltas[1] = 0 - TotalChutesDelta;
            for (var i = 2; i < deltas.Length; i++)
            {
                int nextDelta = random.Next(1, (0 - TotalChutesDelta) - 1);
                if (deltas.Contains(nextDelta))
                {
                    i--;
                    continue;
                }
                deltas[i] = nextDelta;
                Debug.WriteLine(deltas[i]);
            }

            Array.Sort(deltas);
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfChutes; i++)
            {
                deltas[i] = deltas[i + 1] - deltas[i];
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfChutes; i++)
            {
                var startSquareNumber =
                    random.Next(1 + deltas[i], (size * size));
                var startSquare = GetSquare(board, startSquareNumber);
                var endSquare =
                    GetSquare(board, startSquareNumber - deltas[i]);
                if (!startSquare.HasChuteOrLadder &&
                    !endSquare.HasChuteOrLadder)
                {
                    chutes.Add(new ChuteOrLadder
                    {
                        StartSquareNumber = startSquareNumber,
                        EndSquareNumber = startSquareNumber - deltas[i]
                    });
                    board[startSquare.Coordinates.Item1,
                        startSquare.Coordinates.Item2].HasChuteOrLadder = true;
                    board[endSquare.Coordinates.Item1,
                        endSquare.Coordinates.Item2].HasChuteOrLadder = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    i--;
                }
            }
            return chutes;
        }

        private List<ChuteOrLadder> GenerateLadders(BoardSquare[,] board)
        {
            var ladders = new List<ChuteOrLadder>();
            var numberOfLadders = random.Next(1, board.GetLength(0));
            int[] deltas = new int[numberOfLadders + 1];
            deltas[0] = 0;
            deltas[1] = TotalLaddersDelta;
            for (var i = 2; i < deltas.Length; i++)
            {
                int nextDelta = random.Next(1, TotalLaddersDelta);
                if (deltas.Contains(nextDelta))
                {
                    i--;
                    continue;
                }
                deltas[i] = nextDelta;
            }

            Array.Sort(deltas);
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLadders; i++)
            {
                deltas[i] = deltas[i + 1] - deltas[i];
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLadders; i++)
            {
                var startSquareNumber =
                    random.Next(2, (size * size) - (deltas[i] + 1));
                var startSquare = GetSquare(board, startSquareNumber);
                var endSquare =
                    GetSquare(board, startSquareNumber + deltas[i]);
                if (!startSquare.HasChuteOrLadder &&
                    !endSquare.HasChuteOrLadder)
                {
                    ladders.Add(new ChuteOrLadder
                    {
                        StartSquareNumber = startSquareNumber,
                        EndSquareNumber = startSquareNumber + deltas[i]
                    });
                    board[startSquare.Coordinates.Item1,
                        startSquare.Coordinates.Item2].HasChuteOrLadder = true;
                    board[endSquare.Coordinates.Item1,
                        endSquare.Coordinates.Item2].HasChuteOrLadder = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    i--;
                }
            }
            return ladders;
        }

        private BoardSquare GetSquare(BoardSquare[,] board, int squareNumber)
        {
            int row = (board.GetLength(0) * board.GetLength(0) - squareNumber)
                / board.GetLength(0);
            int column = 0;
            if (row % 2 == 0)
            {
                column = (board.GetLength(0) -
                    (squareNumber % board.GetLength(0))) % board.GetLength(0);
            }
            else
            {
                column = (squareNumber - 1) % board.GetLength(0);
            }
            return board[row, column];
        }

        private void PrintBoard(BoardSquare[,] board)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < board.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < board.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Debug.Write(board[i, j] + "\t");
                }
                Debug.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### ChuteOrLadder

```
namespace ChutesAndLaddersBoardGenerator
{
    internal class ChuteOrLadder
    {
        internal int Delta
        {
            get
            {
                return EndSquareNumber - StartSquareNumber;
            }
        }

        internal int EndSquareNumber { get; set; }
        internal int StartSquareNumber { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return StartSquareNumber + "\t" + EndSquareNumber + "\t" + Delta;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Snakes & ladders. Please :)

Comment: @AdamCopley Why?

Comment: Just a fun off topic comment demanding the original name for the game.

Comment: @AdamCopley I think you're around my age and chutes is what it's only  ever been called here in the US. In fact I didn't even know it was ever called "snakes" until creating the challenge. Not that snakes *isn't* the original name.

Comment: 67 to 70 is a ladder? And 70 to 31 is a chute? Broke my rule! Go up and fall down :(

Comment: Wait, is this the first entry? :D

Comment: @EBrown first *intentional* entry

Comment: @Raystafarian So there are some unintentional entries?

Comment: [Just one](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/129951/arduino-snakes-and-ladders)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### class Generator

> ```
> internal Generator(int size)
>   {
>       if (size % 2 != 0)
>       {
>           throw new Exception("Board size must be even!");
>       }
>       else if (size < 2)
>       {
>           throw new Exception("Board size must be positive!");
>       }
>       this.size = size;
>       random = new Random();
>   }
> ```

The correct exception would be an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` instead of an `Exception`. You should always throw the most suitable exception.

In addition you won't need an `else if` just two `if` will do.

---

The `List<ChuteOrLadder> GenerateChutes` is doing too much. You should extract the generation of the `deltas` to a separate method. It will be more readable and easier to maintain and will remove the code duplication happening in `GenerateLadders()` and `GenerateChutes()`.

I don't like the manipulation of the looping variable either. Try to find a way to do it differently.

Both points can be done like so

```
private int[] GenerateDelta(int deltaUpperLimit, int secondDeltaValue, int maxRandomValue)
{
    int[] deltas = new int[deltaUpperLimit + 1];
    deltas[0] = 0;
    deltas[1] = secondDeltaValue;

    for (var i = 2; i < deltas.Length; i++)
    {
        int nextDelta = random.Next(1, maxRandomValue);
        while (deltas.Contains(nextDelta))
        {
            nextDelta = random.Next(1, maxRandomValue);
        }
        deltas[i] = nextDelta;
    }

    Array.Sort(deltas);

    for (var i = 0; i < deltaUpperLimit; i++)
    {
        deltas[i] = deltas[i + 1] - deltas[i];
    }
    return deltas;
}
```

Some more code duplication in the methods generating ladders and chutes

> ```
> for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLadders; i++)
> {
>     var startSquareNumber =
>         random.Next(2, (size * size) - (deltas[i] + 1));
>     var startSquare = GetSquare(board, startSquareNumber);
>     var endSquare =
>         GetSquare(board, startSquareNumber + deltas[i]);
>     if (!startSquare.HasChuteOrLadder &&
>         !endSquare.HasChuteOrLadder)
>     {
>         ladders.Add(new ChuteOrLadder
>         {
>             StartSquareNumber = startSquareNumber,
>             EndSquareNumber = startSquareNumber + deltas[i]
>         });
>         board[startSquare.Coordinates.Item1,
>             startSquare.Coordinates.Item2].HasChuteOrLadder = true;
>         board[endSquare.Coordinates.Item1,
>             endSquare.Coordinates.Item2].HasChuteOrLadder = true;
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         i--;
>     }
> }
> ```

which can be removed by having an (badly named) `AddItem()` method like so

```
private bool AddItem(int startSquareNumber, int delta)
{
    var startSquare = GetSquare(board, startSquareNumber);
    if (startSquare.HasChuteOrLadder)
    { 
        return false;
    }

    var endSquare = GetSquare(board, startSquareNumber + delta);
    if (endSquare.HasChuteOrLadder)
    {
        return false;
    }

    ladders.Add(new ChuteOrLadder
    {
        StartSquareNumber = startSquareNumber,
        EndSquareNumber = startSquareNumber + delta
    });
    board[startSquare.Coordinates.Item1,
        startSquare.Coordinates.Item2].HasChuteOrLadder = true;
    board[endSquare.Coordinates.Item1,
        endSquare.Coordinates.Item2].HasChuteOrLadder = true;

    return true;
}
```

Implementing these changes will lead to

```
private List<ChuteOrLadder> GenerateChutes(BoardSquare[,] board)
{
    var chutes = new List<ChuteOrLadder>();
    var numberOfChutes = random.Next(2, board.GetLength(0));

    int[] deltas = GenerateDelta(numberOfChutes, 0 - TotalChutesDelta, (0 - TotalChutesDelta) - 1);

    int sizeSquared = size * size;
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfChutes; i++)
    {
        var randomMinValue = 1 + deltas[i];
        var startSquareNumber =
            random.Next(randomMinValue, sizeSquared);

        while (!AddItem(startSquareNumber, deltas[i]))
        {
            startSquareNumber =
            random.Next(randomMinValue, sizeSquared);
        }
    }
}

private List<ChuteOrLadder> GenerateLadders(BoardSquare[,] board)
{
    var ladders = new List<ChuteOrLadder>();
    var numberOfLadders = random.Next(1, board.GetLength(0));

    int[] deltas = GenerateDelta(numberOfLadders, TotalLaddersDelta, TotalLaddersDelta);

    int sizeSquared = size * size;
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLadders; i++)
    {
        var randomMaxValue = sizeSquared - deltas[i] + 1;
        var startSquareNumber = random.Next(2, randomMaxValue);

        while (!AddItem(startSquareNumber, deltas[i]))
        {
            startSquareNumber =
            random.Next(2, randomMaxValue);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Why do you use a `Tuple<int, int>` which is hard to read if accessing the values instead of having a simple small struct/class `Position/Coordinate` having only `Row, Col` or `X,Y` as variables/properties ? This would improve the readability of e.g

```
board[startSquare.Coordinates.Item1, startSquare.Coordinates.Item2].HasChuteOrLadder = true;
board[endSquare.Coordinates.Item1, endSquare.Coordinates.Item2].HasChuteOrLadder = true;
```

---

#### internal class ChuteOrLadder

Seeing an `Or` inside a class name usually indicates that that class has too many responsibilities which isn't the case here. I would suggest to rename this class to something else and then have

```
internal class Chute : RenamedChuteOrLadder
{

}
internal class Ladder : RenamedChuteOrLadder
{

}
```

to make it more clear with what you are dealing. This would involve some bigger refactoring but it will be worth it if you need to understand the code in 6 months.

---

Comment: I originally did have a different class for `Chute` and `Ladder` with an interface for them, but there were no differences apart from the class name, so I opted for the single class (which I admit is not named well).

Answer (score 5):

Your algorithm for getting a collection of random deltas could be improved.  It checks for collisions each number it adds, which is O(n) each time, and it keeps creating a new random number until there isn't a collision, which could go on forever.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/110570/480799) is an algorithm that is O(n):

```
static class RandomExtensions
{
    public static void Shuffle<T>(this Random rng, T[] array)
    {
        int n = array.Length;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            int k = rng.Next(n--);
            T temp = array[n];
            array[n] = array[k];
            array[k] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

This:

> ```
> public void LoadChutesAndLadders(
>     List<ChuteOrLadder> chutesAndLadders)
> {
>     chutesAndLaddersDisplay.DataSource = chutesAndLadders;
>     int totalDelta = 0;
>     foreach (var chuteOrLadder in chutesAndLadders)
>     {
>         totalDelta += chuteOrLadder.Delta;
>     }
>     totalDeltaLabel.Text = "Total Delta: " + totalDelta;
> }
> ```

Can be written more concisely using LINQ:

```
public void LoadChutesAndLadders(
    List<ChuteOrLadder> chutesAndLadders)
{
    chutesAndLaddersDisplay.DataSource = chutesAndLadders;
    int totalDelta = chutesAndLadders.Sum(x => x.Delta);
    totalDeltaLabel.Text = "Total Delta: " + totalDelta;
}
```

Comment: I really should have thought of that. Thanks for pointing it out.